# show images in Django templates

Tags: python, django, image, templates

Can someone help me with this issue: I have a Django porject,

**in settings.py**

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/hl/workspace/beer/media'
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'C:/Users/hl/workspace/beer/media'
 )
```

**and in models.py**

```
image1= models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**and in url.py**

```
 (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

**in views**

```
def allBeer(request): 
      beers=Beer.objects.all().order_by("name")
      context={'beers': beers}
      return render_to_response('AllBeers.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**and in html**

```
 {%for beer in beers %}
    <p>
        <a href="/beers/{{beer.slug}}/">
            <img scr="{{beer.image1.url}}">{{beer}}
        </a>
    </p>
 {% endfor%}
```

It has not problem to load images, but images wont show in html file. I have searched and read a lot from internet but I still couldn't figure out.

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
image1= models.ImageField(upload_to=images)


from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from project_name import settings

admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...........
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()


<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{beer.image1}}">
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
SITE_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'staticfiles'),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates'),
)
```

Comment: can't still not show the images with
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{beer.image1}}">{{beer}}</a>

Comment: i have changed to these codes, but nothing has changed, can still not show the images :(

Comment: theProject
       beer
   __init__
   settings
   url
       beerApp
   admin 
   models
   views
   (and so on)  
       media
   (different pictures from uploading)
       templates
   html files
       manage.py
      (and so on)

Comment: cant do anything with my low reputation:(,  
 but the structure is like: porject(beer(settings.py, url.py ...)beerApp(views.py, models.py...)media('all images in upload to here')template('all html files')manage.py)

Comment: still not work, where did i do wrong :O I need 10 to post a picture , thanks for you upvote :)

Comment: There is something you have missed. We can try it again tomorrow, I need to sleep. Or maybe someone will help you later.

Comment: thanks for your help, I will try to contact you again if I haven't solve the problem till tomorrow. have a nice dream. :)

Comment: would yo still like to help me with that today, in you suggestion os.path.dirname(__file__), will point to my 'C:\\eclipse\\plugins\\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\\pysrc' folder, but i dont have any medie og static folder in this folder, it doesnt look like a good idea to create any new folder there:/

Comment: Can we continue this in chat

Comment: media folder is automatically created when you upload images

Comment: where can i catch you in chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25460/discussion-between-hln-and-catherine)

Answer (score 8):

You're messing with the `src` attribute of the image. It should just be -

```
<img src="{{beer.image1.url}}" /> <!-- from the media url -->
```

Don't add anything to the end - django know's the url to serve the image from - that's what the ImageField on the model does.

I don't know that there's actually anything wrong with your url conf, but the pattern recommended in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#django.conf.urls.static.static) is -

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: can't still not show the images with 
<img src="{{beer.image1.url}}">{{beer}}</a> :(

Comment: This should work if your on the dev server (ie using `python manage.py runserver`). If you're running it on a live server you will need to check your setup to correctly serve static files - this isn't handled by django, but by the webserver you have installed. For more info - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/

Comment: I use Django build-in server.

Comment: OK, try changing your url conf - loose the line you've included in your question and use the code in my updated answer.

Comment: sir @AidanEwen i accidently down voted your answer please edit your answer so that i can undo my downvote

Comment: @JoseKj - thanks, I've updated the outdated link to the django docs

Answer (score 7):

Follow this steps to load an image on your Django Template:

1. Add this to your settings file:

```
    
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

2. Create a folder named **“media”** under your project root directory, meaning the folder will be on the same level as your apps
3. Add these to your main urls.py

```
from . import views, settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your path goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

4. In your model, use ImageField for the field being used for the image.

```
    
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
```

5. Add below to your template to load your images

If you are loading dynamically from a context object, use a syntax similar to this:

```
    
img src="{{ obj1.photo.url }}"
```

If you are loading statically, when the file name is already determined, use:

```
img src="/media/project_name/photo.png"
```

Comment: it gives me 404, when I hit ip:8000:/media/project_name/photo.png.

Comment: Sorry, do you have any photo in `/media/project_name/` directory?

Comment: oky, now its working , I was adding this static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) to app's urls.py file instead main urls.py file of main project directory.

Answer (score 0):

the location of your images are important. it has to be in the static folder and that has to be defined in the settings.