# How do I load an image, which was uploaded earlier ,onto a HTML file?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.6

So I set up profile pic upload as guided by http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/login.html.
Then I found the second answer(by user Raisins) to useful for my purpose and implemented it [Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django). As I've been that this answer is outdated, I've also tried the solution offered here for migration [Get rid of get_profile() in a migration to Django 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613315/get-rid-of-get-profile-in-a-migration-to-django-1-6) which hasn't improved my situation

Then in my views, I add required details including the image to a dictionary, and render i to the HTML page. It looks as though the UserProfile isn't returning the right object.

```
u=User.object.get(username__exact=request.user)
profile=UserProfile.objects.get(user=u)
global client
client['login']=True
client['name']=u.username
client['password']=u.password
client['email']=u.email
client['picture']=profile.picture
return render(request,'index.html',{'client':client})
```

And when I try to display the details on HTML page, everything except image is loaded.
I tried

```
<img src="profile_images/{{client.picture}}">
```

where profile_images is in the root directory. I inspected the  element and I find this

```
<img src="/static/profile_images/%7B%7B%20client.picture%20%7D%7D">
```

where I was expecting "1.jpg" instead of "%7B%7B%20client.picture%20%7D%7D".

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175032/show-images-in-django-templates

Comment: I tried the solutions suggested here, they didn't work

Comment: try like:  <img src="{{ media_url }}{{ client.picture.url }}">

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that {{client.picture.url}} or {{client.url}} isn't returning the right value

Comment: what is the model field of `picture`?

Comment: picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

Comment: one lame question, did you install `PILLOW`?

Answer (score 0):

[Raisin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965883/3107299) is outdated. Please [don't use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#auth-profile-module) AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in Django 1.6 anymore. In fact, you don't even need to handle the `post_save` signal.

Based on the same tutorial, you will find the code for your view:

```
u = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

try:
    p = UserProfile.objects.get(user=u)
except:
    p = None

return render(request,'index.html',{'client':client, 'userprofile':p})
```

In your template use:

```
    {% if userprofile.picture %}
        <img src="{{ userprofile.picture.url }}"  />
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: When my code runs 'userprofile'<--> p ends up being None. So it still doesn't work

Comment: With a little tweaking, 'user profile'<--> p is not None but now I can't even access details such as name or email which I could do before

Comment: That is expected if the user has not created a profile yet. Try to use the admin or django shell to create a profile for that user.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the problem. You can access username  in the template using {{ user.username }}

Comment: I have edited the question based on your help, but the original problem of image not loading persists.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static client.picture %}"  />
```