# display uploaded files django

Tags: python, django

i have a problem with django. I need to display my files in single page

So i create model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images/', blank=True, null=True)
profile_text = models.TextField()
profile_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
profile_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and form

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['profile_img', 'profile_title']
```

then view

```
def cabinet(request):
form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
    obj = UserProfile(profile_img=request.FILES['profile_img'])
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.profile_user = request.user
    obj.save()
    return redirect(reverse(cabinet))
return render(request, 'cabinet.html', {'form': form})
```

I try use view

```
def user_page(request):
profile = UserProfile.objects.all()
return render(request, 'user_page.html', {'profile':profile})
```

and

```
{% for img in profile %}
{{ img.profile_img }}
{% endfor %}
```

it is not work 
Help me plz, i try to read documentation but it doesn't help

Comment: And how does it work? Does it display anything? The code you pasted should print a path to each 'profile.profile_img' and what is your actual output?

Comment: yes, it is print  path to my images   media/img/oOOSlWzBOSQ.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the code you pasted will only print path to your each `profile.profile_img`. And so is the `profile_img` attribute, it only stores a path to the image you uploaded, not the image itself. In order to use the media files uploaded to your website you need to specify a `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in your `settings.py`.

Then you need to append it to your `urls.py`. You might want to look here also: [show images in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175032/show-images-in-django-templates)

After you have done so, to display an image in template just use `HTML` tag

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ img.profile_img }}" />
```

Comment: I did it, as you said. Image doesn't display. I inspect element in browser: <img src="media/images/FoEBCX-KyDk.jpg">  it should work                           my settings:                                                                                         MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MIDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Comment: and i have 2 urls, main file for my project:  urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^/cabinet', include('comments.urls') ),
    url(r'^', include('user_login.urls')),                                                                           And fo my app:  urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.cabinet, name='cabinet' ),
    url(r'^/user_page/$', views.user_page, name='user_page'),
     
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: And what is the problem? Is there any exception or the code just doesn't work? You can try to View page source and manually check out the urls to images, if there are any

Answer (score 1):

I did it, as you said. Image doesn't display. I inspect element in browser:  it should work
my settings:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

And i have 2 urls, main file for my project:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^/cabinet', include('comments.urls') ),
url(r'^', include('user_login.urls')),]
```

and for my app:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.cabinet, name='cabinet' ),
url(r'^/user_page/$', views.user_page, name='user_page'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: The problem might be that your previous images are not uploaded to the `MEDIA_ROOT`, because you specified it afterwards. Try to upload new images and check it out

Comment: doensn't work too. I think problem with url or in my model

Comment: Hmm, have you searched your project files for the uploaded images? If they are there, are they inside the `MEDIA_ROOT` dir?

Comment: yes i find mistake in settings. it was MIDIA not MEDIA, in model i fixed upload_to, now it 'images/'. And django create folder in MEDIA_ROOT. But it's doesnt help

Comment: So when you upload an image it should be in `/media/images/`. And what path does your `<img src="?" />` use? Easiest way to check it all out is to `View page source` in your browser

Comment: files upload to /media/images.  in browser <img src="images/3N7QtulTgx0.jpg"> problem with media_url?

Comment: you probably use `<img src="{{ img.profile_img }}" />` instead of `<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ img.profile_img }}" />` right?

Comment: no i use <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ img.profile_img }}" />

Comment: Ok, you might need to add it also to your context processors. In `settings.py` add new line `"django.core.context_processors.media"` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Comment: now in browser <img src="/media/images/oOOSlWzBOSQ.jpg"> and image still broken

Comment: So it seems like a problem with files serving. I assume you get 404 when you try to reach `/media/images/oOOSlWzBOSQ.jpg` via your browser?

Comment: Do you have an import statement `from django.conf import settings` in your urls.py?

Comment: yes, i finaly fix it! use + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) in my main url, not in app url. thanks a lot! Thank you for your patience to my bad english and django

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and i just def a **str** for my pic field to return the self.pic.url in the model itself, and in the template i just used {{pic}}.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct this line
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' MIDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

to

MEDIA_URL = '/media/' MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

it should be MEDIA  not MIDIA